# Set certain values to NA with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to do something like this with dplyr (data set = dat, variable = x):

```
dat$x[dat$x<0]=NA
```

Should be simple but this is the best I can do at the moment.  Is there an easier way?

```
dat = dat %>% mutate(x=ifelse(x<0,NA,x))
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use `replace` which is a bit faster than `ifelse`:

```
dat <-  dat %>% mutate(x = replace(x, x<0, NA))
```

You can speed it up a bit more by supplying an index to `replace` using `which`:

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(x = replace(x, which(x<0L), NA))
```

On my machine, this cut the time to a third, see below.

Here's a little comparison of the different answers, which is only indicative of course:

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1e6))
system.time(dat %>% mutate(x = replace(x, x<0, NA)))
       User      System     elapsed
       0.03        0.00        0.03 
system.time(dat %>% mutate(x=ifelse(x<0,NA,x)))
       User      System     elapsed
       0.30        0.00        0.29 
system.time(setDT(dat)[x<0,x:=NA])
       User      System     elapsed
       0.01        0.00        0.02 
system.time(dat$x[dat$x<0] <- NA)
       User      System     elapsed
       0.03        0.00        0.03 
system.time(dat %>% mutate(x = "is.na<-"(x, x < 0)))
       User      System     elapsed
       0.05        0.00        0.05 
system.time(dat %>% mutate(x = NA ^ (x < 0) * x))
       User      System     elapsed
       0.01        0.00        0.02 
system.time(dat %>% mutate(x = replace(x, which(x<0), NA)))
       User      System     elapsed
       0.01        0.00        0.01
```

(I'm using dplyr_0.3.0.2 and data.table_1.9.4)

---

Since we're always very interested in benchmarking, especially in the course of data.table-vs-dplyr discussions I provide another benchmark of 3 of the answers using microbenchmark and the data by akrun. Note that I modified `dplyr1` to be the updated version of my answer:

```
set.seed(285)
dat1 <- dat <- data.frame(x=sample(-5:5, 1e8, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(1e8))
dtbl1 <- function() {setDT(dat)[x<0,x:=NA]}
dplr1 <- function() {dat1 %>% mutate(x = replace(x, which(x<0L), NA))}
dplr2 <- function() {dat1 %>% mutate(x = NA ^ (x < 0) * x)}
microbenchmark(dtbl1(), dplr1(), dplr2(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# dtbl1() 1.091208 4.319863 4.194086 4.162326 4.252482    20
# dplr1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20
# dplr2() 6.251354 5.529948 5.344294 5.311595 5.190192    20
```

Comment: Perhaps akrun is willing to update his answer. He seems to be running the latest versions of both packages.

Comment: This seems like a case where the base way is much simpler syntax wise.

Comment: I **cannot** reproduce your benchmark! `data.table` is faster.

Answer (score 22):

The most natural approach in dplyr is to use the `na_if` function.

For one variable:

```
dat %<>% mutate(x = na_if(x, x < 0))
```

For all variables:

```
dat %<>% mutate_all(~ na_if(., . < 0))
```

If interested in replacing a specific value, instead of a range for all variables:

```
dat %<>% mutate_all(na_if, 0)
```

Note that I am using the `%<>%` operator from the `magrittr` package.

Comment: Thanks, good to know!  I don't think this function was available when I first asked the question.

Comment: `na_if(x, y)` doesn't seem to work in this example where y is a condition that contains x. Compare: `quakes %>%
  mutate(depth = na_if(depth, depth > 610))` doesn't mutate anything, but the following does: `quakes %>%
  mutate(depth = replace(depth, depth > 610))`

Comment: Looking for an example where I set one variable to NA based on some other condition ... none of this page seems to do that?

Comment: @AgileBean example needs ```, NA``` at the end, such that: ```quakes %>% mutate(depth = replace(depth, depth > 610, NA))```

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. `na_if` compares the first argument with the second, and return NA if they are equal. It doesn't take a list index as its second argument. See the [na_if docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html?q=replace#value).

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `is.na<-` function:

```
dat %>% mutate(x = "is.na<-"(x, x < 0))
```

Or you can use mathematical operators:

```
dat %>% mutate(x = NA ^ (x < 0) * x)
```

Comment: Looking for an example where I set one variable to NA based on some other condition ... none of this page seems to do that?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `data.table`, the below code is faster

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[x<0,x:=NA]
```

#### Benchmarks

Using `data.table_1.9.5` and `dplyr_0.3.0.9000`

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(285)
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(-5:5, 1e7, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(1e7))

dtbl1 <- function() {as.data.table(dat)[x<0,x:=NA]}
dplr1 <- function() {dat %>% mutate(x = replace(x, x<0, NA))}

microbenchmark(dtbl1(), dplr1(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#dtbl1() 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20  a 
#dplr1() 2.06654 2.064405 1.927762 1.795962 1.881821 1.885655    20   b
```

#### Updated Benchmarks

Using `data.table_1.9.5` and `dplyr_0.4.0`.  I used a slightly bigger dataset and replaced `as.data.table` with `setDT` (Included @Sven Hohenstein's faster function as well.)

```
set.seed(285)
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(-5:5, 1e8, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(1e8))
dat1 <- copy(dat)
dtbl1 <- function() {setDT(dat)[x<0,x:=NA]}
dplr1 <- function() {dat1 %>% mutate(x = replace(x, x<0, NA))}
dplr2 <- function() {dat1 %>% mutate(x = NA ^ (x < 0) * x)} 

microbenchmark(dtbl1(), dplr1(), dplr2(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#dtbl1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20  a 
#dplr1() 2.523945 2.542412 2.536255 2.579379 2.518336 2.486757    20   b
#dplr2() 1.139216 1.089992 1.088753 1.058653 1.093906 1.100690    20  a
```

#### Updated Benchmarks2

At the request of @docendo discimus, benchmarking again his "new" version of `dplyr`using `data.table_1.9.5` and `dplyr_0.4.0`.

NOTE: Because there is a change in @docendo discimus code, I changed `0` to `0L` for the data.table`

```
set.seed(285)
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(-5:5, 1e8, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(1e8))
dat1 <- copy(dat)
dtbl1 <- function() {setDT(dat)[x<0L, x:= NA]}
dplr1 <- function() {dat1 %>% mutate(x = replace(x, which(x<0L), NA))}
dplr2 <- function() {dat1 %>% mutate(x = NA ^ (x < 0) * x)} 

microbenchmark(dtbl1(), dplr1(), dplr2(), unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#dtbl1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20 a  
#dplr1() 2.186055 2.183432 2.142293 2.222458 2.194450 1.442444    20  b 
#dplr2() 2.919854 2.925795 2.852528 2.942700 2.954657 1.904249    20   c
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(-5:5, 25, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(25))
```

Comment: On my computer, dplyr is little faster. I have `data.table_1.9.5`, `dplyr_0.4.0`.

Comment: @Khashaa I used `data.table_1.9.5` and `dplyr_0.3.0.9000`.  So, may be there is a version difference.

Comment: `data.table_1.9.4` and `dplyr_0.3.0.2` Similar results as @Akrun. Then I upgraded to `dplyr_0.4.0`, `dplyr` is still ~2x faster.

Comment: I run @akrun's original code `set.seed(24);dat <- data.frame(x=sample(-5:5, 25, replace=TRUE), y=rnorm(25));dtbl1 <- function() {as.data.table(dat)[x<0,x:=NA]};dplr1 <- function() {dat %>% mutate(x = replace(x, x<0, NA))};microbenchmark(dtbl1(), dplr1(), unit='relative', times=20L)`

Comment: @akrun, how about updating your benchmark with the same as in my answer (at the bottom) but the latest versions of data.table/dplyr?

Comment: @docendodiscimus  Yes, did updated the benchmark.  Please check :-)

Comment: @akrun, this (random down votes) has been happening to David and me as well.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the comment.  After some thought, I came to the conclusion that this could be because I posted a data.table solution for a `dplyr` specific question.

Comment: @akrun, it is also tagged "r". The fact that they did not write a note already tells a lot. This is SO. Not a dplyr/data.table forum.

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace` directly on the `x` column and not using `mutate` also works.

```
dat$x <- replace(dat$x, dat$x<0, NA)
```