# Replacing values in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to do a somewhat complicated task in R.

I have a `data frame` with (for simplicity's sake) three columns.

Column 1 is a string.
Column 2 is an integer.
Column 3 is an integer.

I want to take all the observations which contain a certain substring in Column 1 AND that have an exact value for Column 2, and replace the third Column with the number 1.

That is, I have the following `dataframe`:

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = c("bob","jane","bob","bobby","bob","jane","bobby","bob","jane","bob"),
                x2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                x3 = c(13,22,3,34,10,23,53,42,13,35))
```

And, I want to select observations where Column 1 contains bob and Column 2==1, and change the third column to 1, so that I end up with:

```
y1 <- c("bob","jane","bob","bobby","bob","jane","bobby","bob","jane","bob")
y2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
y3 <- c(1,22,1,1,1,23,53,42,13,35)
y <- data.frame(y1,y2,y3)
```

I want to do this across a really, really big dataset. It is not feasible to split up the dataset and put it back together.
I have tried using `grep`, but it's not working when I try to do both matches at once. Also, I have tried subsetting, but then I'd have to split apart the `dataframe` and put it back together.
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: `grepl` is often more useful because it supports combinations of logical tests with vectorized `&` and `|`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With R's capacity for logical indexing using the `[<-` function, this is really quite easy:

```
> x$x3[ grepl("bob", x$x1) & x$x2 == 1] <- 1
> x
      x1 x2 x3
1    bob  1  1
2   jane  1 22
3    bob  1  1
4  bobby  1  1
5    bob  1  1
6   jane  2 23
7  bobby  2 53
8    bob  2 42
9   jane  2 13
10   bob  2 35
```

To read the code you should see it as: "for every line of `x` where column 'x1' has "bob' and column 'x2' is equal to 1 ,... you assign the value 1 to column 'x3'." If you wanted to have a new object with that value, you could make a copy of x with `y <- x` and working on that instead.

Comment: Something similar with `ifelse` : `ifelse((x$x2 == 1 & grepl("bob", x$x1)), 1, x$x3)`

Comment: @RonakShah `ifelse` isn't so great as a general strategy for replacement. Try `ifelse(c(TRUE,FALSE), Sys.Date()+1, Sys.Date()) # doesn't return dates`

Comment: @Frank Ohh..In which case should we avoid to use `ifelse` then? and what about the run time? is it the same or `ifelse` is slow?

Comment: @RonakShah Yeah, it's generally slow http://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/1191259 but nonetheless sometimes more convenient than the alternatives. I try to avoid it.

Comment: @Frank Thank you so much. That is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice answer from user *akrun* using the `dplyr` package to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013850/change-value-of-variable-with-dplyr) and a faster variant from user *docendo discimus* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909000/set-certain-values-to-na-with-dplyr). In your case, the code would be :

`x %>% mutate(x3 = replace(x3, x1 == 'bob' & x2 == 1, 1))`

or

`x %>% mutate(x3 = replace(x3, which(x1 == 'bob' & x2 == 1), 1))`

If you want to update x directly, you could combine with the `%<>%` operator from the `magrittr` package as:

`x %<>% mutate(x3 = replace(x3, x1 == 'bob' & x2 == 1, 1))`

Comment: How would you do it for strings that *include* 'bob', such as 'bobby' in the example? Thanks.

Comment: Then, I'd call `grepl` (which returns a logical) to the rescue: 
x %<>% mutate(x3 = replace(x3, grepl('bob', x1) & x2 == 1, 1))

Answer (score 1):

```
x1   <- c("bob","jane","bob","bobby","bob","jane","bobby","bob","jane","bob")
x2   <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
x3   <- c(13,22,3,34,10,23,53,42,13,35)
x    <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

rows <- grepl("bob", x[,1]) & x[,2] == 1 # Logical Selector Of Rows

x[rows, 3] <- 1
```

except for notation, the main diff between my answer and @42-'s answer is that my logical-selector-of-rows phrase operates only on the dataframe, whereas @42- references one of the original vectors (likely by oversight).

```
      x1 x2 x3
1    bob  1  1
2   jane  1 22
3    bob  1  1
4  bobby  1  1
5    bob  1  1
6   jane  2 23
7  bobby  2 53
8    bob  2 42
9   jane  2 13
10   bob  2 35
```

Comment: There really is no material difference between `x[rows, 3]` and `x$x3[rows]` .

Comment: .... just style/readability.  However,  I was referring to the diff between x2 and x$x2 (which in the meantime you have corrected in your answer)

Comment: Yeah. Somebody already fixed that oversight. And I edited the question to remove the unnecessary vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `data.table` package for high performance:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[grepl('bob', x1) & x2==1, x3:=1][]

#       x1 x2 x3
# 1:   bob  1  1
# 2:  jane  1 22
# 3:   bob  1  1
# 4: bobby  1  1
# 5:   bob  1  1
# 6:  jane  2 23
# 7: bobby  2 53
# 8:   bob  2 42
# 9:  jane  2 13
#10:   bob  2 35
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking out for the sub-string `grep`can be used in that case along with the '*ifelse*' function. With x as the data frame and wanting *x$x3* to be changed do the following,

1: Find those with the required sub-string

```
req_sub<-grep("bob",x$x1)
```

This will return all the positions of x3 where there is a match in the sub-string

2: Make the changes in column x3

```
x$x3[grep("bob",x$x1)]<-ifelse(x[req_sub,]$x2==1,1,x[req_sub,]$x3)
```

The following will be the output

```
      x1 x2 x3
1    bob  1  1
2   jane  1 22
3    bob  1  1
4  bobby  1  1
5    bob  1  1
6   jane  2 23
7  bobby  2 53
8    bob  2 42
9   jane  2 13
10   bob  2 35
```