# How to use apply or dplyr to conditionally transform specific variables

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I'm working with 3 data frames with similar structure but different values. I'd like to transform/mutate specific variables based on a condition in the variable to be transformed AND a second variable in the data set. Other variables in the data set should be left intact.

In my example data, I'd like to transform columns VAR1-3 to NA IF the corresponding AGE < 65 AND if the column it self has value 0.

```
foo <- data.frame('AGE'=c(50,65,66,40,70,25,65,67,44,56), 'SMOKING'=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1),
              'VAR1'=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0),'VAR2'=c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),'VAR3'=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0))

VARv <- c('VAR1','VAR2','VAR3')
OTHERSv <- c('SMOKING')
AGEVARv <- c('AGE', VARv)
```

As my data sets are large (>2000 variables) and the variables may be in different order, I want to use variable names saved in vectors.

I can do this with the following for loop but would like to learn how to use either dplyr or apply functions

```
for (i in 1: length(VARv)) {foo[,VARv[i]] <- replace(foo[VARv[i]], foo[VARv[i]]==0 & foo$AGE<65, NA)}
```

If I wouldn't have binary variable SMOKING in the data set, I could do

```
foo <- apply(foo, 2,function(y) {
foo[foo==0 & foo$AGE < 65] <- NA
return(foo)
})
```

But this would also transform SMOKING variable.

Question: How do I select and refer to variables in apply function when one of them I want to refer by name and others I want to process automatically?

I have something like this in mind but how do I refer to the variable AGE correctly? This attempt produces 21 columns worth of data with correct NA action but repeats all columns for each of the column (AGE.SMOKING, AGE.AGE, AGE.VAR1..., VAR1.SMOKING, VAR1.AGE, VAR1.VAR1 ETC)

```
b <- data.frame(foo[colnames(foo) %in% OTHERSv], apply(foo[colnames(foo) %in% AGEVARv],2,function(y) {
foo[foo==0 & foo$AGE < 65] <- NA
return(foo)
}))
```

I'd appreciate any insight!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909000/set-certain-values-to-na-with-dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function for reuse

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(dat, varCols, AgeCol){
  Age <- rlang::sym(AgeCol)
  dat %>%
     mutate_at(vars(varCols), funs(replace(., .==0 & (!!Age) < 65, NA)))
}

AgeC <- 'AGE'

f1(foo, VARv, AgeC)
#   AGE SMOKING VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
#1   50       0    1   NA    1
#2   65       0    0    0    0
#3   66       0    0    1    1
#4   40       0    1   NA    1
#5   70       0    0    0    1
#6   25       1    1    1   NA
#7   65       1    0    0    0
#8   67       1    1    0    0
#9   44       1   NA   NA    1
#10  56       1   NA    1   NA
```

---

We can also use `base R`  methods

```
f2 <- function(dat, varCols, AgeCol){
    dat[varCols] <- (NA^(dat[[AgeCol]] < 65 & !dat[varCols]))*dat[varCols]

   dat
}

all.equal(f1(foo, VARv, AgeC), f2(foo, VARv, AgeC), check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I like your first suggestion as it utilizes the variable name vectors. This however seems to produce an error when I try to replicate it: Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  varCols .

Comment: @MerviK  I was using only your example `foo`  It is not clear what you are trying to replicate.  Also, I use `dplyr_0.7.4`  Please check if you have the current version of `dplyr`

Comment: I was replicating/using your solution using the example data. My dplyr var outdated and installing the latest version solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using `case_when()`.

> In my example data, I'd like to transform columns VAR1-3 to NA IF the
>   corresponding AGE < 65 AND if the column it self has value 0.

Here's an example of `case_when()` solving this problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

foo %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(VAR1 = case_when(AGE < 65 & VAR1 == 0 ~ "NA",
                          TRUE ~ as.character(.$VAR1)),
         VAR2 = case_when(AGE < 65 & VAR2 == 0 ~ "NA",
                          TRUE ~ as.character(.$VAR2)),
         VAR3 = case_when(AGE < 65 & VAR3 == 0 ~ "NA",
                          TRUE ~ as.character(.$VAR3)))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
     AGE SMOKING  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1    50       0     1    NA     1
 2    65       0     0     0     0
 3    66       0     0     1     1
 4    40       0     1    NA     1
 5    70       0     0     0     1
 6    25       1     1     1    NA
 7    65       1     0     0     0
 8    67       1     1     0     0
 9    44       1    NA    NA     1
10    56       1    NA     1    NA
```