# How to change an element of the original dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble:

```
library('tibble')

df <- tibble(
  ticker = c("first", "second", "third"),
  status = c(T,T,T)
)

> df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ticker status
 1 first  TRUE  
 2 second TRUE  
 3 third  TRUE
```

I want to change the status of 'first' to FALSE in the original df.

But when I run this code:

```
library('dplyr')

df %<>%
  filter(ticker=='first') %>%
  mutate(
   status = F
  )
```

I get my original df only with the first row

```
> df
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  ticker status
1 first  FALSE
```

Instead of:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ticker status
1 first  FALSE 
2 second TRUE  
3 third  TRUE
```

Comment: use `mutate(status = ifelse(ticker=='first', F, T))`

Comment: Other solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909000/set-certain-values-to-na-with-dplyr ...

Comment: `df %>%  mutate(status = replace(status, ticker == "first", FALSE))` or just `df %>%  mutate(status = ticker != "first")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function `case_when`:

```
library('tibble')

df <- tibble(
    ticker = c("first", "second", "third"),
    status = c(T,T,T)
)

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    mutate(status = case_when(
        ticker == "first" ~ F,
        TRUE ~ T
    ))
```

This is the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ticker status `case_when(ticker == "first" ~ F, TRUE ~ T)`
  <chr>  <lgl>  <lgl>                                       
1 first  TRUE   FALSE                                       
2 second TRUE   TRUE                                        
3 third  TRUE   TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R

```
 within(df, status[ticker == "first"] <- FALSE )
```

Comment: using base R it is much simpler df[df$ticker=='first', 'status'] <- F

Comment: Sure, but if you have longer names for your dataframe it get's clearer and easier using within. That's the whole point of `within`.